# retrofit 2 не выполняется get запрос

Tags: android, retrofit2

Возникла проблема. При реализации даного запроса
http://mykolavoitovych.zzz.com.ua/tests/registration.php?email=vojtovydfh@tmu.edu.ua&login=vitaglic&password=mycola&speciality=2

В логах ничего нет и запрос не выполянется. Вот метод

```
@GET(TestApiConstant.PATH_REGISTRATION)
fun register(@Query("email") email: String, @Query("login") login: String, @Query("password") password: String, @Query("speciality") speciality: String): Single<RegisterResponce>
```

Константы

```
const val BASE_URL = "http://mykolavoitovych.zzz.com.ua/tests/"
const val PATH_REGISTRATION = "registration.php"
```

Метод через который я обращаюсь к API. В дебаге проверял доходит сюда и останавливается

```
fun register(email: String, login: String, password: String, speciality: Int): Single<RegisterResponce> = apiMethods
        .register(email, login, password, speciality.toString())
        .onErrorMapException()
```

Comment: Если вы показали весь код, то да, вы его не выполняете. На `rx` источник надо подписаться. типа `register(...).subscribe()`

Comment: Дело в том, что я по такому принципу делаю и другие запроси и все ок

Comment: Покажите место непосредственного запуска кода, то где у вас стартует подписка.

Comment: Моя ошибка, не заметил. Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать подписку `register(...).subscribe()`